# Is 2^(2n) = O(2^n)

Tags: math, big-o

```
Is 2(n+1) = O(2n)?
```

I believe that this one is correct because `n+1 ~= n`.

---

```
Is 2(2n) = O(2n)?
```

This one seems like it would use the same logic, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that

```
2n+1 = 2(2n)
```

and

```
22n = (2n)2
```

From there, either use the rules of Big-O notation that you know, or use the definition.

Comment: So, what is the Big-o for 2^2n?

Comment: @DylanCzenski 2^2n = (2^2)^n = O(4^n)

Comment: What are the actual names of these two?

Answer (score 32):

First case is obviously true - you just multiply the constant C in by 2.

Current answers to the second part of the question, look like a handwaving to me, so I will try to give a proper math explanation. Let's assume that the second part is true, then from the definition of [big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), you have:

[image]

which is clearly wrong, because there is no such constant that satisfy such inequality.

Answer (score 14):

Claim: 2^(2n) != O(2^n)

Proof by contradiction:

1. Assume: 2^(2n) = O(2^n)
2. Which means, there exists c>0 and n_0 s.t. 2^(2n) <= c * 2^n for all n >= n_0
3. Dividing both sides by 2^n, we get: 2^n <= c * 1
4. Contradiction! 2^n is not bounded by a constant c.

Therefore 2^(2n) != O(2^n)

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you just left off the O() notation on the left side.

O(2^(n+1)) is the same as O(2 * 2^n), and you can always pull out constant factors, so it is the same as O(2^n).

However, constant factors are the only thing you can pull out.  2^(2n) can be expressed as (2^n)(2^n), and 2^n isn't a constant.  So, the answer to your questions are yes and no.

Comment: `2^(n+1) = O(2^n)` is common, incredibly unfortunate notation for saying *"The order of 2^(n+1) is Big-O (2^n)"*  If I had my way, instead of this terrible O, Ω, Θ notation, we'd use one symbol Θ in conjunction with ≤, ≥, and = to specify order; the above statement would then be written as `Θ(2^(n+1)) ≤ Θ(2^n)`.  Unfortunately, this is simply not the way it works :(

Answer (score 6):

**2<sup>n+1</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>)** because 2<sup>n+1</sup> = 2<sup>1</sup> * 2<sup>n</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>).
Suppose 2<sup>2n</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>) Then there exists a constant c such that for n beyond some n<sub>0</sub>, 2<sup>2n</sup> <= c 2<sup>n</sup>. Dividing both sides by 2<sup>n</sup>, we get 2<sup>n</sup> < c. There's no values for c and n<sub>0</sub> that can make this true, so the hypothesis is false and 2<sup>2n</sup> != O(2<sup>n</sup>)

Answer (score 3):

To answer these questions, you must pay attention to the definition of big-O notation. So you must ask:

is there any constant C such that `2^(n+1) <= C(2^n)` (provided that n is big enough)?

And the same goes for the other example: is there any constant C such that `2^(2n) <= C(2^n)` for all n that is big enough?

Work on those inequalities and you'll be on your way to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

We will use=> `a^(m*n) = (a^m)^n = (a^n)^m`
now,

2^(2*n) = (2^n)^2 = (2^2)^n

so,

(2^2)^n = (4)^n

hence,

O(4^n)

Obviously,

rate of growth of (2^n) < (4^n)

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an solution that would make sense instantly.

Assume that `2^n = X`
(since n is a variable, X should be a variable), then  `2^(2n) = X^2`. So, we basically have `X^2 = O(X)`. You probably already know this is untrue based on a easier asymptotic notation exercises you did.

For instance:

- `X^2 = O(X^2)` is true.
- `X^2+X+1 = O(X^2)` is also true.
- `X^2+X+1 = O(X)` is untrue.
- `X^2 = O(X)` is also untrue.

Think about **polynomials**.